# how do I add missing section to a cylinder

Tags: cycles-render-engine, objects

I have a label that wraps around bottle, however it does not wrap around sufficiently. I need to close the gap, making the label longer but keeping a perfect circular shape (as seen from above). Is there an easy way of doing this or do I need to start again from scratch?

[image]
[image]

Comment: To add a label I suggest you don't add any more geometry (overlapping faces will cause z fighting). Use a texture instead.

Comment: @cegaton Would I apply this texture to the existing faces of the bottle itself? If so and the label has to have rounded corners does the UV unwrap work with images containing transparency?

Comment: @cegaton Am having a few problems with applying a texture (UV unwrapped) to just certain faces only. Have reset scale and rotation and even removed any modifiers to see if they were interfering is there something I am missing? I will upload my blend file.

Comment: Read [Add a transparent image on top of a material](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46424/add-a-transparent-image-on-top-of-a-material/46447#46447)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Duplicate (<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>) a section of the label large enough to fill the gap, (don't move it,) and then rotate it around Z until it does.

Do the rotation in vertex select mode: select all the vertices in the new section, finishing with one of the vertices that's going to lie on the seam, to set it active. Set Snap On to 'Vertex' and 'Active'. The active vertex can the snap to its partner on the other side during a constrained rotation (<kbd>R</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>)

If the label is not conveniently centered on the world origin , choose 2 diametrically opposite vertices from it, and (<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>) send the 3D Cursor to Selection. Then use that as your rotation pivot.

Once the vertices on the seams are coincident, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> bring up the vertex menu, and select 'Remove Doubles'.

Comment: Well I have been trying to make it work but given up. I used the center of origin of the original cylinder as the pivot point after duplication. That seemed to work.  Did you mean (Shift D) when you referred to constrained rotation as this is used for duplication as per your first paragraph? I could not get snap to work. The label had modifiers applied to it  so it was not a straight forward cylinder, maybe this impacted the snap. @Robin Betts

Comment: I'm so sorry, that was a cut-and-paste typo. I've corrected it. When I duplicate faces, I usually move the duplicate a little bit to check it's there (no mouse buttons) , and then right click to drop them where they started. They remain selected. Go to Vertex mode. The corresponding verts are still selected. Shift-click the vert you want to be active twice. That will activate it. Then RZ. all the verts will roll around the bottle.Hover over the vert you want the active vert to join to. Work  with the modifiers switched off, for simplicity.